# Kubectl deploy in Azure Devops Release Pipeline failed with exit code 1 for AKS Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, kubectl, azure-aks

I would request if someone can help in why my release pipeline to AKS cluster is failing. I'm using Azure Devops Release pipeline.

```
2020-09-02T10:56:33.1944594Z ##[section]Starting: kubectl create app and service or apply
2020-09-02T10:56:33.2380678Z ==============================================================================
2020-09-02T10:56:33.2381778Z Task         : Kubectl
2020-09-02T10:56:33.2384698Z Description  : Deploy, configure, update a Kubernetes cluster in Azure Container Service by running kubectl commands
2020-09-02T10:56:33.2385174Z Version      : 1.173.0
2020-09-02T10:56:33.2386143Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-09-02T10:56:33.2387216Z Help         : https://aka.ms/azpipes-kubectl-tsg
2020-09-02T10:56:33.2387656Z ==============================================================================
2020-09-02T10:56:34.9075560Z Downloading: https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.7.0/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe
2020-09-02T10:56:37.8112374Z Caching tool: kubectl 1.7.0 x64
2020-09-02T10:56:37.9135761Z Prepending PATH environment variable with directory: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\kubectl\1.7.0\x64
2020-09-02T10:56:40.4896282Z Could not fetch Kubectl version. Please make sure that the Kubernetes server is up and running.
2020-09-02T10:56:40.5241929Z [command]C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\kubectl\1.7.0\x64\kubectl.exe apply -f D:\a\r1\a\_praneshshzl_AKSCICDDEMO\aksdeploy.yml -o json
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8395443Z {
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8397440Z     "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8398489Z     "kind": "Deployment",
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8399348Z     "metadata": {
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8400030Z         "annotations": {
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8401188Z             "deployment.kubernetes.io/revision": "2",
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8404455Z             "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"apiVersion\":\"apps/v1\",\"kind\":\"Deployment\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"name\":\"aspx-deployment\",\"namespace\":\"default\"},\"spec\":{\"replicas\":2,\"selector\":{\"matchLabels\":{\"app\":\"asp-net\"}},\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"app\":\"asp-net\"}},\"spec\":{\"containers\":[{\"image\":\"***/drop:40\",\"name\":\"asp\",\"ports\":[{\"containerPort\":80}]}]}}}}\n"
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8406762Z         },
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8407640Z         "creationTimestamp": "2020-09-02T07:19:54Z",
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8408392Z         "generation": 2,
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8409051Z         "name": "aspx-deployment",
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8409752Z         "namespace": "default",
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8410403Z         "resourceVersion": "19157",
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8411229Z         "selfLink": "/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments/aspx-deployment",
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8412093Z         "uid": "57c18e4d-0583-43bc-b0c4-58d6bb2c9069"
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8413323Z     },
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8413859Z     "spec": {
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8414348Z         "progressDeadlineSeconds": 600,
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8414799Z         "replicas": 2,
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8415097Z         "revisionHistoryLimit": 10,
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8415368Z         "selector": {
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8415640Z             "matchLabels": {
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8416109Z                 "app": "asp-net"
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8416360Z             }
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8416549Z         },
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8416778Z         "strategy": {
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8417054Z             "rollingUpdate": {
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8417341Z                 "maxSurge": "25%",
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8417658Z                 "maxUnavailable": "25%"
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8417927Z             },
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8418189Z             "type": "RollingUpdate"
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8418422Z         },
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8418649Z         "template": {
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8419141Z             "metadata": {
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8419452Z                 "creationTimestamp": null,
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8419748Z                 "labels": {
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8420044Z                     "app": "asp-net"
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8420308Z                 }
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8420525Z             },
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8420745Z             "spec": {
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8422686Z                 "containers": [
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8422953Z                     {
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8423661Z                         "image": "***/drop:40",
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8424053Z                         "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8424416Z                         "name": "asp",
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8424731Z                         "ports": [
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8425016Z                             {
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8425324Z                                 "containerPort": 80,
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8425698Z                                 "protocol": "TCP"
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8426026Z                             }
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8426285Z                         ],
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8426562Z                         "resources": {},
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8426957Z                         "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8427380Z                         "terminationMessagePolicy": "File"
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8427696Z                     }
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8427918Z                 ],
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8428205Z                 "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8428542Z                 "restartPolicy": "Always",
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8428896Z                 "schedulerName": "default-scheduler",
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8429231Z                 "securityContext": {},
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8429585Z                 "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8429873Z             }
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8430792Z         }
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8431012Z     },
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8431285Z     "status": {
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8431559Z         "availableReplicas": 2,
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8431825Z         "conditions": [
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8432059Z             {
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8432383Z                 "lastTransitionTime": "2020-09-02T07:19:54Z",
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8432798Z                 "lastUpdateTime": "2020-09-02T07:37:15Z",
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8433255Z                 "message": "ReplicaSet \"aspx-deployment-84597d88f5\" has successfully progressed.",
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8434044Z                 "reason": "NewReplicaSetAvailable",
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8434679Z                 "status": "True",
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8435244Z                 "type": "Progressing"
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8435605Z             },
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8435825Z             {
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8436146Z                 "lastTransitionTime": "2020-09-02T10:53:01Z",
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8436562Z                 "lastUpdateTime": "2020-09-02T10:53:01Z",
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8436957Z                 "message": "Deployment has minimum availability.",
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8437364Z                 "reason": "MinimumReplicasAvailable",
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8437756Z                 "status": "True",
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8438064Z                 "type": "Available"
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8438304Z             }
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8438510Z         ],
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8438765Z         "observedGeneration": 2,
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8439067Z         "readyReplicas": 2,
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8439325Z         "replicas": 2,
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8439604Z         "updatedReplicas": 2
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8439834Z     }
2020-09-02T10:56:49.8440256Z }
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0434980Z error: error validating "D:\\a\\r1\\a\\_praneshshzl_AKSCICDDEMO\\aksdeploy.yml": error validating data: the server could not find the requested resource; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0592077Z commandOutput{
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0592764Z     "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0593476Z     "kind": "Deployment",
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0593853Z     "metadata": {
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0594453Z         "annotations": {
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0617018Z             "deployment.kubernetes.io/revision": "2",
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0619826Z             "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"apiVersion\":\"apps/v1\",\"kind\":\"Deployment\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"name\":\"aspx-deployment\",\"namespace\":\"default\"},\"spec\":{\"replicas\":2,\"selector\":{\"matchLabels\":{\"app\":\"asp-net\"}},\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"app\":\"asp-net\"}},\"spec\":{\"containers\":[{\"image\":\"***/drop:40\",\"name\":\"asp\",\"ports\":[{\"containerPort\":80}]}]}}}}\n"
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0622683Z         },
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0623075Z         "creationTimestamp": "2020-09-02T07:19:54Z",
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0623735Z         "generation": 2,
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0624085Z         "name": "aspx-deployment",
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0624371Z         "namespace": "default",
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0624697Z         "resourceVersion": "19157",
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0628209Z         "selfLink": "/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments/aspx-deployment",
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0628683Z         "uid": "57c18e4d-0583-43bc-b0c4-58d6bb2c9069"
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0628948Z     },
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0629156Z     "spec": {
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0629632Z         "progressDeadlineSeconds": 600,
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0629958Z         "replicas": 2,
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0630236Z         "revisionHistoryLimit": 10,
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0633694Z         "selector": {
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0634104Z             "matchLabels": {
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0634389Z                 "app": "asp-net"
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0634654Z             }
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0634863Z         },
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0635116Z         "strategy": {
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0635383Z             "rollingUpdate": {
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0635685Z                 "maxSurge": "25%",
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0636003Z                 "maxUnavailable": "25%"
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0636322Z             },
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0636572Z             "type": "RollingUpdate"
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0636821Z         },
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0637050Z         "template": {
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0637316Z             "metadata": {
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0637611Z                 "creationTimestamp": null,
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0637922Z                 "labels": {
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0638230Z                     "app": "asp-net"
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0638483Z                 }
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0638819Z             },
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0639105Z             "spec": {
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0639388Z                 "containers": [
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0639651Z                     {
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0640045Z                         "image": "***/drop:40",
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0640435Z                         "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0640782Z                         "name": "asp",
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0641098Z                         "ports": [
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0641395Z                             {
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0642030Z                                 "containerPort": 80,
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0642527Z                                 "protocol": "TCP"
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0642853Z                             }
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0643111Z                         ],
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0643405Z                         "resources": {},
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0643802Z                         "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0644232Z                         "terminationMessagePolicy": "File"
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0644550Z                     }
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0644768Z                 ],
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0645058Z                 "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0645398Z                 "restartPolicy": "Always",
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0645752Z                 "schedulerName": "default-scheduler",
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0646087Z                 "securityContext": {},
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0646605Z                 "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0646902Z             }
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0647131Z         }
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0647308Z     },
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0647518Z     "status": {
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0647785Z         "availableReplicas": 2,
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0648069Z         "conditions": [
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0648292Z             {
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0648700Z                 "lastTransitionTime": "2020-09-02T07:19:54Z",
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0649116Z                 "lastUpdateTime": "2020-09-02T07:37:15Z",
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0649585Z                 "message": "ReplicaSet \"aspx-deployment-84597d88f5\" has successfully progressed.",
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0650020Z                 "reason": "NewReplicaSetAvailable",
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0650354Z                 "status": "True",
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0650662Z                 "type": "Progressing"
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0650920Z             },
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0651117Z             {
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0651508Z                 "lastTransitionTime": "2020-09-02T10:53:01Z",
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0652363Z                 "lastUpdateTime": "2020-09-02T10:53:01Z",
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0652807Z                 "message": "Deployment has minimum availability.",
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0653184Z                 "reason": "MinimumReplicasAvailable",
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0653520Z                 "status": "True",
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0653840Z                 "type": "Available"
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0654095Z             }
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0654285Z         ],
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0654538Z         "observedGeneration": 2,
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0654831Z         "readyReplicas": 2,
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0655099Z         "replicas": 2,
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0655360Z         "updatedReplicas": 2
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0655592Z     }
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0655767Z }
2020-09-02T10:56:50.0655889Z 
2020-09-02T10:56:52.6885299Z ##[error]The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\kubectl\1.7.0\x64\kubectl.exe' failed with exit code 1
2020-09-02T10:56:52.7480636Z ##[section]Finishing: kubectl create app and service or apply
```

My aksdeploy.yml file is at https://github.com/praneshshzl/AKSCICDDEMO/blob/master/aksdeploy.yml

My image to deploy is a docker hub image based on windows at https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/praneshhzl/drop

Comment: this has something to do with my yml file mentioned above, can anyone please check and rectify it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this was something to do in the kubectl apply task in release pipeline. We have to go to right pane, scroll down, expand "advanced" and in version spec check the box **"check for latest version"**. My pipeline built completed successfully. There was no issues in my deployment yaml.

Enabling this option ensures proper latest version of kubectl.exe is downloaded
onto the VSTS agent

```
Downloading: https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt
2020-09-02T12:18:39.3539227Z Downloading: https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.19.0/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe
2020-09-02T12:18:40.7266540Z Caching tool: kubectl 1.19.0 x64
2020-09-02T12:18:40.8028720Z Prepending PATH environment variable with directory: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\kubectl\1.19.0\x64
2020-09-02T12:18:43.3630075Z ==============================================================================
2020-09-02T12:18:43.3632157Z            Kubectl Client Version: v1.19.0
2020-09-02T12:18:43.3633193Z            Kubectl Server Version: v1.16.13
2020-09-02T12:18:43.3633757Z ==============================================================================
```